# Infinite sum of stable random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

We know that: 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \stackrel{d}{=} cX+d,
\end{equation}
when $X_i, X$ are i.i.d. random variables which come from any $\alpha$-stable distribution, $c, d \in \mathbb{R}$. Does the relation also occurs when $ n \rightarrow \infty$?

To be specific, let $X_i, X$- as above. Do we have series of $a_n \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $b_n\in \mathbb{R}$ such that:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n a_n(X_i -b_n)\stackrel{d}{=}X
\end{equation}

Comment: The question is not clear to me. Do you want the limit to exist almost surely or only in distribution?

Comment: Only in distribution.